# Regex/Grep to filter strings in text file

Tags: grep

I need a regex/grep command for a text file with multiple strings in it and I want to return an error if there are strings other than String1 and String2. TIA!

```
String1... String2... String3... String4... etc
```

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be as expected

```
if grep -v 'excel' document.txt | grep -v 'word'; then
  echo "error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single pattern matching either word or excel or an empty line using an alternation and check if there is a reversed result, and use `--quiet` to not write to standard output.

```
if grep --quiet -v 'word\|excel\|^[[:space:]]*$' document.txt; then
  echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: Hi @The Fourth bird, I'm actually looking to error if the file contains other than the strings 'word and/or excel'.

Comment: @user1905 I have changed the answer, now echoing error when there is a reversed result.

Comment: thank you for the help. But it still shows error when there is word, excel and some other strings in the text file. My requirement is, in the text file when there is only word and excel, it should not throw any error. But if any other string (along with word and excel), it should error.

Comment: @user1905 it does exactly that. See [only word or excel or empty lines](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEADv@xXrGqgKofca/6IHoa2QxK0JlKam8XHov8eqx2GGMXp2OW83pfFjaVYAqM/1SeysTqiUQgJ@Wx4AXiFegfYAvsdb5AmlvD88J5RPLL6yXX5lu1yapponbbnquoMo/huxbumIyfEIiGxdQOIYQyTofc4f) vs [with a word that should not be there](https://tio.run/##JYxLDoIwFAD37xTP0gQ1adhjvQULE8CkrQ/bhFBs62fB3SvocjKT0SranItdpd1U6RUAmktz5nujEkopkQF9DI2QKCaAtw83YAcAN@A90IxCPJ6OEooXlpvsll/eLde2reOsDNV9f@Tl/8XXNzthsjQBIhnrkVEIPjAYXM5f)

Comment: yes it works now with  |^[[:space:]]*$'. Thanks a ton.